# Jquery Validate plugin rules method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a **asp.net** form where I am trying to use Jquery Validation plugin. I am trying to add the rules using javascript using the [`rules`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) method. so i tried something like this

```
$('#btnSave').on('click', function () {
    $("#txtAmount").rules("add", {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        messages: {
            required: "Required input",
            minlength: jQuery.format("Please, at least {0} characters are necessary")
        }
    });
    $('form').validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

I have set the `ClientIDMode="Static"` so that i can use the contorl IDs directly. However, this is not working. Can anyone tell me where is the problem. I can't seem to put my finger on it.

here is a **<kbd>[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85KR4/2/)</kbd>**

Comment: in your jsfiddle, use this line `$("#id1").rules("add", {` I will continue testing the jsfiddle. bbiab

Comment: @JPHellemons, silly me. just a typo. but it still doesn't work.

Comment: true, expected it to be a small typo. i am looking at your jsfiddle. i am hitting an `Shell form does not validate jsfiddle` at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is correct except the order.
At first you should call `validate`, and just after that you can call `rules`.

http://jsfiddle.net/85KR4/3/

Comment: I should have tried that first. again, silly me. Thanks for your prompt response.

Comment: Not quite _"correct except the order"_... the `click` handler is totally superfluous.

Comment: @Sparky, you're absolutely right. Didn't notice anything but main mistake - my bad.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, as explained in the accepted answer, you must call `.validate()` (initialization) before calling the `.rules()` method.

**However:**

1)  Since `.validate()` is only the initialization method (only gets called *once*), there is no need to wrap it inside a `click` handler.  The plugin already *automatically* captures the click event.

2)  In this example case there is no need for a `submitHandler` that only contains a `form.submit()` inside, since that's already the default behavior of the `submitHandler`.  Leaving the `submitHandler` out entirely will yield the same result.  Although, if you need to use ajax or perform some other code on submit, then by all means, use the `submitHandler`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('form').validate({
        // other rules and options
    });

    $("#id1").rules("add", {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        messages: {
            required: "Required input"
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/85KR4/5/** (regular form action called on successful submission)

**DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/85KR4/7/** (ajax called on successful submission)